# Example where image of measurable set under measurable function is not measurable

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Let $(E,\mathscr{E})$ and $(F,\mathscr{F})$ be measurable spaces. Let $f:E\rightarrow F$ be a measurable relative to $\mathscr{E}$ and $\mathscr{F}$. When is $f(A)\notin\mathscr{F}$, where $A\in\mathscr{E}$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Let $\mathscr E$ be the power set of $E$, $\mathscr F=\{\emptyset,F\}$ and $f$ a constant function.

Comment: *When is* $f(A)\notin\mathscr{F}$, *where* $A\in\mathscr{E}$ --- Do you want a specific example or do you want some kind of characterization for when this is possible? Your title seems to ask the former, but your question seems to ask the latter.